# write peripheral.name Xcode

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have an app that connects to a bluetooth LE peripheral.  Is it possible to change the peripheral's name from the app.  In other words I want to rewrite the peripherals localized name from the central device.  I can get the name through the advertised data and only connect to the peripheral if it have a certain name.  but I would like the user to be able to change the peripheral's name so only they can connect to that specific peripheral from the app.

I'm not sure if my peripheral allows it or not.  How would I check and How would I write the new name??

I have used the following code to get the service device information and then to get the manufacturers name

```
if([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]]) {
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        NSLog(@"discovered characteristic %@", characteristic.UUID);
        if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A29"]]) {
            NSLog(@"Found Notified Characteristic %@", characteristic);
            self.mycharacteristic2 = characteristic;
            [self.testPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
            [self.testPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:mycharacteristic2];
            NSLog(@"value:%@",mycharacteristic2.value);

        }
    } NSLog(@"services%@",service);}
```

however if I substitute 2A00 (which is supposed to be the UUID for the device Name) I get nothing.

I have also tried to use 1800 for generic access and 1801 for generic information but I don't get any response for the device name 2A00.

I do get a log that 1801 is Device information but no information for 2A00 which is supposed to be Device Name.  Does anyone know how to access the Device Name characteristic UUID?

Comment: Only if the peripheral allows it.

Comment: 'm not sure if my peripheral allows it or not. How would I check and How would I write the new name??

Comment: See its documentation See what characteristics is writable.

Comment: I think that the peripheral name is an advertisement date , not a characteristic or are they the same?

Comment: Well, if the device don't allow renaming, you can't. A collegue (working on the BLE device firmware part) made specially a characteristic for me to be able to rename the device (it will advertise a different local name).

Comment: As far as I can tell, iOS 'hides' certain characteristics and presents them as separate API concepts. CBPeripheral's 'name' is one example of this, it initially uses the advertisement data to populate the name but iOS silently performs a read of the GAP 'device name' characteristic and updates this property. Similarly I believe when it receives a notification on that characteristic it sends the app a peripheralDidUpdateName callback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `properties` property of the characteristic. You'd be looking for `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite`.

Also, are you absolutely sure the peripheral supports `2A00`? Try using the app LightBlue to browse all the available services and chacteristics.